# How to access Linux environment variables in angular 2?

Tags: node.js, linux, angular

I am trying to access a Linux environment variable in angular 2 but I am not sure how to do it. For example if I export a variable in terminal i can access it in node but I don't know how to access this variable in angular 2.
`$ export HOST_IP="192.168.1.1"`
I can access this environment variable in node like: `process.env.HOST_IP`. Could anyone please tell me how to access it in angular 2.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS applications are run in a Server. So a NodeJS app can access the attributes of the server (Ex : Environmental variables).

But an Angular application runs on the browser. Thus it cannot access to the details of the machine that it is run on (there are some exceptions of course, but I'll not discuss them here).

Said that, if your true requirement is to change certain variables depending on the build of the Angular app (ex : test build, debug build, production deployment build), You can use the environment files. There are plenty of guidelines on the internet on how to do that. Few of them are,

- https://alligator.io/angular/environment-variables/
- https://medium.com/beautiful-angular/angular-2-and-environment-variables-59c57ba643be
- https://medium.com/@natchiketa/angular-cli-and-os-environment-variables-4cfa3b849659

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. My use case seems to be different. I don't have the values on build time. I have to set/change values right before I access the application in browser.

Comment: From where do these values come from? Can you describe the exact use case?

Comment: These values come from environment variables in Linux shell. Suppose i already have built UI code. There are certain values that are unknown on build time. I have to pass those values on run time whenever code runs in browser.

Comment: Then on build time, prior to build, add them to the `environments.ts` and start the build.

Comment: This is not how my use case works. Anyhow thanks for your help.

Comment: Can u pls provide any one steps for angular 5, Currently im getting my local system variables.